# AWS CDK and how to update ECS without getting stuck

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I got a simple CDK stack to deploy a docker container via `ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Servic`. Deployments work great. But when I'm upgrading, e.g. by setting the docker container to `hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.1-beta.1`, updates take forever, with the last output being something like:

```
12:23:01 | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
| HasuraStack
12:23:32 | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ECS::Service
| Hasura/Service/Service
```

I think that this has to do with desiredCapacity and minCapacity being set to 1. As soon as I go to AWS console and manually set them to 0, the update works. I've tried different configurations for minCapacity/maxCapacity/desiredCapacity without success.

**The best outcome would be to have 2 instances running, the old one that slowly drains and the new one that all new traffic gets redirected to. Is there any easy way to achieve something alike and get updates through? A short downtime would also be acceptable.**

Here is the code:

```
const cluster = new Cluster(this, 'Cluster', {
  vpc: props.vpc,
});

cluster.addCapacity('ASGroupCapacity', {
  instanceType: new InstanceType(props.instanceType || 't3.micro'),
});

this.service = new ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service(this, 'Hasura', {
  publicLoadBalancer: true,
  cluster,
  // assignPublicIp: props.hasuraServiceProps?.assignPublicIp || true,
  domainName: `${props.subDomain}.${props.zone.zoneName}`,
  domainZone: props.zone,
  protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
  memoryReservationMiB: 512,
  desiredCount: 1,
  taskImageOptions: {
    image: ContainerImage.fromRegistry('hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.0'),
    containerPort: 8080,
    environment: {
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: props.connectionString,
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_TELEMETRY: 'true',
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: 'true',
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: `{"type": "HS256", "key": "${this.jwtSecret.secretValue.toString()}"}`,
    },
    secrets: {
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: Secret.fromSecretsManager(this.secret),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to share, I have run into similar situation.

For cluster capacity, I have set the following:

```
    cluster.addCapacity("my-scaling-group", {
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
        ec2.InstanceClass.T3A,
        ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL
      ),
      minCapacity: 1,
      maxCapacity: 3
    });
```

What I find the most important bit, is to do with deregistration delay, the default is 5 mins (=300 seconds).

```js
service.targetGroup.setAttribute("deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds", "30")
```

The whole redeployment takes around 10 mins